# how to combine date and time in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have 2 values:

```
var dt1 = dtFromDate.Value;
var tm1 = tmFromTime.Value;


dt1 = 12/5/2013 12:00:00 AM

tm1 = 11/5/2013 9:00:00 AM
```

i want to make datetime as  : 12/5/2013 9:00:00 AM

how can it be possible?

Comment: Not an answer, but a tip: before too long you'll realise Date and Time handling in .NET is a travesty. At which point, see http://nodatime.org.

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't call your variables `dt1` and similar. `date` would be a much better name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new `DateTime` using overloaded [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/272ba130%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(
                    dt1.Year, 
                    dt1.Month, 
                    dt1.Day, 
                    tm1.Hour, 
                    tm2.Minute, 
                    tm2.Second,
                    tm2.Millisecond);
```

Comment: You are loosing Milliseconds from `tm2`

Comment: Correct, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can take the date part of `dt1` by accessing `Date`, the time part of `tm1` by accessing `TimeOfDay` and then combine them using `+`:

```
dt1.Date + tm1.TimeOfDay
```

Comment: @downvoter Could you explain what do you think is wrong with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use that code, using `Date` property to get just date part and `Time` property to get just time part:

```
var dt1 = DateTime.Parse("12/5/2013 12:00:00 AM"); // this is just a sample date
var tm1 = DateTime.Parse("11/5/2013 9:00:00 AM"); // this is just a sample date

var newDate = dt1.Date.Add(tm1.TimeOfDay); // the code to use
```

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime` object is immutable so in order to get the date from one `DateTime` object, but the time from another - you must create new `DateTime` object. 
There is two ways for doing it:

Create new DateTime with constructor overload:

```
DateTime date1 = 
    new DateTime(dt1.Year, dt1.Month, dt1.Day, tm1.Hour, tm1.Minute, tm1.Second);
```

Parse string to DateTime:

```
var dateToParse = 
      String.Concat(dt1.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd ", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), 
                    tm1.ToString("HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
var date1 = 
      DateTime.ParseExact(dateToParse, "yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```